# how to use form_for to create a nested rescource in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

job.rb

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :companies do
     resources :jobs
end
```

I want to use form_for to create a new job, so I do this:

```
<%= form_for(@company_job do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for(:company_job, url: company_jobs_path do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

but both of them get error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/jobs"
```

how can I post a form to `/company_jobs_path (url like this /companys/:company_id/jobs(.:format))`

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

view:

```
form_for @company do |f|
  # company fields go here
  f.fields_for :jobs do |f2|
    # job fields go here
  end
end
```

model:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs
end
```

Comment: thank you for your help.  I get an another answer like this:                       `<%= form_for([@company, @company.jobs.build]) do |f| %>`   I try it, and success.